# How do I attach back to the WEBrick server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

I started the server in detached mode (-d), how do I attach back to it so that I can kill the server).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yu can see the id of the ruby process:

```
ps aux | grep ruby
username       17731   0.1  1.6  3127008  67996   ??  S     2:00PM   0:01.42 /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby script/rails s -d
```

and kill process by id:

```
kill -9 17731
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `pgrep ruby` with `kill -9`:

```
kill -9 `pgrep ruby`
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way:

```
kill -9 `cat tmp/pids/server.pid`
```