# If I only can type command lines in other Terminal after execute rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

When I run :

```
$ rails server
```

It comes:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.1 application starting in development on  http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.6.2 (ruby 2.3.0-p0), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

So I can not type in command in this Terminal, so if is I must open an other Terminal by <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to type commands?

Comment: rails server & . Later use fg to get it back. to put it in the background, use Ctrl+Z and bg to push it to the background.

Comment: @Sairam You should make an answer out of this (or I'll do).

Comment: @Felix created as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
rails server -d
```

it will run rails server as detached.

Comment: if use `rails server -d` , how to close the server when I want to quit the server ?

Comment: @aircraft 2 useful answers, which should explain how to kill detached server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164091/how-to-stop-a-daemon-server-in-rails + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386093/how-do-i-attach-back-to-the-webrick-server

Answer (score 0):

if using a mac just type <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> to open a new terminal tab and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to kill the server you can also you use the rails console which is `rails c` to run.

Answer (score 0):

to start any job in the background on bash, append it with `&`

```
rails server &
```

You can use `fg` to get it to foreground.

To put any the job back to the background, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> and then `bg` to push it to the background.

> NOTE: All stdout/stderr will continue to write to the terminal on `bg`

Comment: whats the `bg` use? how to write it in the terminal.

Comment: it sends the stopped process with `Ctrl+Z` to the background. You can look at the list of jobs with `jobs` command

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by a comment of @Sairam to the original question (where he asks me to create an answer, too):

These explanations should be true for most if not any Linuxes/Unixes .

If you append an `&` to your command, it will be directly send to the background:

```
rails server &
```

If you enter

```
jobs
```

you should now see that there is a job running the background.

To get this command "back" (if it did not crash, it is still running anyway), call

```
fg
```

.
To make a break and temporarily stop this command from executing, use Ctrl+Z.
You are now back in the shell. `jobs` will show you what happened (job is now "Stopped").

So, you have a "Stopped" job and are in the terminal. To push this job to the background (and let it continue to do its job), call

```
bg
```

(for "background" ...).

Now, if you want to have it back, call (you get it) `fg`, and so on...

Note that using this approach (versus e.g. `rails server -d`), you have slightly more/easier control, and your command will get killed with your terminal-session. So, when you close your terminal, the rails server will go byebye, too. You would usually use `screen` (or other alternatives) if you don't want that.